# Realizar acciones por cada elemento de un array Javascript

Tags: javascript

***No me refiero a literalmente el elemento en si , sino mas bien su numero.
osea supongamos el siguiente array:***

```
var disparos = {

           colorBala: this.color;
           potenciaBala: this.pB;
           mL: this.mL;

        }

    var b = []; // Este array recibe valores segun la cantidad de disparos

    var b = [disparos,  disparos]; // Suponiendo que disparó 2 balas:
```

Suponiendo que

> disparos
>
> representa un disparo y que tiene sus *propiedades , colores , funciones*
>   *, etc*.

Entonces quiero que si ha disparado 1 vez osea: `var b = [disparos];`

se cree un canvas, el problema es que con `forEach` lo realiza al elemento en sí , *como si cambiara sus propiedas, etc,* yo solo quiero que actue según la cantidad de elementos, ***iterando por cada disparo que puede llegar a ser decenas y así por cada disparo crear un dibujo canvas.***

Comment: Eduardo , muéstranos que has intentado , `disparo` es una clase? `this.sb` serán objetos de esa clase ? sí es así se puede iterar sobre ellos y verificar alguna propiedad o ejecutar algún método del elemento.

Comment: Pregunta editada @Dev.Joel

Comment: Debería leer , https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: lo veré @Dev.Joel!

Comment: a ver si te entiendo, `b` es una **matriz** donde cada elemento corresponde a un objeto, entonces con la propiedad `length` puedes obtener la **cantidad de objetos** que hay en `b`, ahora `b[0]` apunta al **primer objecto** de `b` y así con cada uno `b[0]`, `b[1]`, `b[2]`, `b[n]`, luego con `b[0]["nombre"]` accedes a cada propiedad del objecto donde **"nombre"** es valga la redundancia el **nombre la propiedad del objeto**, ahora lo que no entiendo y con el debido respeto pregunto: que es lo que tu no entiendes para hacer lo que quieres?

Comment: gracias fwBasic, pero ya me han respondido , era lo de abajo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no importan los elementos que contiene el array ya que se realizará una acción por cada elemento contenido, lo que importa es el número de elementos contenidos en el array, sólo hay que obtener el tamaño del array, iterar ese número de veces, lanzando la acción para cada iteración.

Ejemplo:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var n = fruits.length;

for ( var i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    console.log( "Lanzada la acción: " + ( i + 1 ));
}
```

Resultado:

```
Lanzada la acción: 1
Lanzada la acción: 2
Lanzada la acción: 3
Lanzada la acción: 4
```